# Centering a display:table div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a full width wrapper div. Inside it, there's another div set as `display: table`.

I've set the wrapper as `text-align: center`, but the table div is not getting centered. Why is that? What am I missing here in order to center the `display: table` div horizontally inside the wrapper?

[**See JsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gpq95d26/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tb">
        <div class="tb-cell">1</div>
        <div class="tb-cell">2</div>
        <div class="tb-cell">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    text-align: center;
}

.tb {
    display: table;
    width: 100px;
    background: silver;
}

.tb-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

> The [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) CSS property describes how inline content like
>   text is aligned in its parent block element.

Then, it can't center an element with `display: table`, because that isn't inline content.

But you can use `inline-table` instead:

```css
.tb {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gpq95d26/2/)

Comment: Thanks... My main interest was knowing why it didn't work, and this answer perfeclty explained... Marking as right as soon as I can...

Comment: Just a note that `inline-table` is supported on modern browsers and IE9+, IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE, and it's not supported in IE7 and earlier

Comment: @LcSalazar Yes, doesn't work on old IE, but I think the same applies for `table` and `table-cell`.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the class:

```
.tb {
    display: table;
    width: 100px;
    background: silver;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gpq95d26/3/

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark Oriol's answer as correct because my main interest was knowing why it wasn't working... But +1 for your solution has more compatibility....